# Deleted record in ember is not removed from collection

Tags: ember.js

I am building a simple CRUD app. I have a list of records fetched from the server, click on the first and I am on the `show` page for that record with a `delete` button that ties into this action on the controller:

```
destroy: function() {
  this.content.deleteRecord()
  this.store.commit()
  this.transitionTo('usersIndex')
}
```

I know the record is deleted, I can see it deleted on the server. The AJAX request is successful. However, the record still shows up on the index page. If I do a hard refresh from the server it is now gone.

My Router for `usersIndex` is the following:

```
App.UsersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Users.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Anyone found a reasonable work around? (I'm having the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

After calling deleteRecord you must save it for the ember data.

```
destroy: function() {
  this.content.deleteRecord()
  this.content.get('isDeleted');
  this.content.save()
  this.store.commit()
  this.transitionTo('usersIndex')
}
```

Or alternatively you can sue destroyRecord which deleted thh record from both backend and ember data

```
destroy: function() {
      this.content.destroyRecord()
      this.transitionTo('usersIndex')
    }
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

The solution I applied on my project was to enhance usersIndex to filter out any isDeleted records e.g.

In the template something like:

```
{{#unless user.isDeleted}}
  {{render 'user' user}}
{{/unless}}
```

Also one can leverage the afterModel hook to test for isDeleted e.g.:

```
afterModel: function(model){
    if ((!model.get('users').isAny('isDeleted',false)) || model.get('users.length') === 0){
        this.send('exitUserIndex');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a new question?

Comment: Updated it to remove my question.