# Ember delete/destroy does not always remove record from view

Tags: ember.js

**Update**

This is probably related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187239/deleted-record-in-ember-is-not-removed-from-collection).

When I delete a record either with rec.delete() and rec.save() or rec.destroy() it removes the record but sometimes leaves child model fragments in the view which disappear if I refresh the screen.  Any ideas on possible causes/solutions of this issue?

My router map

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('cart', function () {
        this.route("index", { path: "/" });
        this.route('product', {path: 'products/:product_id'});
    });
});
```

User starts in cart.index then selects the product which transitions to ProductRoute. Then when they delete the product in my ProductController:

```
    delete: function () {
        var rec = this.get('model'),
            self = this;
        rec.deleteRecord();
        rec.save().then(function () {
            self.transitionToRoute('cart.index');    
        });
    }
```

However when cart.index is reshow, it SOMETIMES leaves child model remnants of the hierarchical multi model Product in the view other times it deletes the record correctly.  Any ideas?  Alternatively how can I cause cart.index to refresh its model?

In the afterModel hook of CartIndexRoute I can see that the product record is flagged as isDeleted - but it should be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can find so far is to enhance the cart.index route to filter out any isDeleted records.  something like this:

```
afterModel: function(model){
    if ((!model.get('products').isAny('isDeleted',false)) || model.get('products.length') === 0){
        this.send('exitCartIndex');
    }
}
```

and then in my template:

```
{{#unless product.isDeleted}}
  {{render 'sumCartProduct' product}}
{{/unless}}
```

If anyone has a better solution that would be awesome.